# Launching python Bokeh application passing options to python

Tags: python, bokeh, visual-studio-code

I'm wanting to launch, and debug a Bokeh application using the vscode launcher. To do this, I think I need to equivalently run python with arguments like `python -m bokeh serve <path-to-directory>`. How can the `launch.json` file be written to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `Python Module` [debug type](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types) along with specifying the rest as [`args` to the program](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_args).

```
"module": "bokeh",
"args": ["serve", "${workspaceFolder}"]
```

The Django debug type might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help. This is what I ended up with ```{
    "name": "Bokeh App",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "module": "bokeh",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
    "args": [
        "serve", 
        "--show",
        "${workspaceFolder}/app"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "env": {},
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "debugOptions": [
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}```